# How to get intellisense for external javascript libraries with es5 and Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am working with project without transpilers. When I want to use external library and use intellisense in Visual Studio Code I would need to use import (which would not work with es5).

Example: I want to use axios library so I install it with npm, add script tag reference to axios.js and write the application code in app.js. I can get intellisense when I do this

`import axios from 'axios';`

but it would fail with es5.

I did find a hacky workaround that gives me intellisense would and not fail with es5:

`var axios = axios || require('axios').default;`

But at least for me this looks too hacky to me just for intellisense :)

I also noticed that for example jquery intellisense also works without import and think the reason is that jquery type definition file does not use module syntax (export) and things are added into global scope. So I am also wondering would it be somehow possible to create my own type definition file to add things into global scope?

Answer (score 4):

Investigated this further and found out that indeed you can just create your own helper type definition file that will import types in module into global scope in order to use this in a ES5 project with global scope:

Create file global.d.ts (name does not matter) in your project with following contents:

```
import { AxiosStatic } from "axios";

declare global {
  const axios: AxiosStatic;
}
```

That wil make intellisense work in global context (in my app.js) without having to use import. Of course only do this when you really can not use modules (global is bad :))

I'll see if I can convince vscode people (who are imho doing excellent job with this text editor :)) that this might be useful addition to the vscode documentation as well (https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/63494)

Answer (score 2):

The above [answer by @realmer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53390495/7475099) is the perfect solution. But I would like to expand it a little with a full example.

#### Complete Example

This is completely a rookie example, no webpack, babel, parcel or anything! No special 3rd party vs code extension for typescript! No need to run any servers too!

I have 3 files in the beginning:

```bash
./index.html
./three.js
./script.js
```

> The external library here was [Three.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/build/three.js)

#### `global.d.ts`

Created this file and have put below code, just like how @realmer did for `Axios` in above answer.

```
import THREE from './three'

declare global {
    const THREE: THREE
}
```

Now we have following files in root folder open inside vs Code:

```bash
./index.html
./three.js
./script.js
./global.d.ts
```

**`index.html`**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Basic Scene</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script text="text/javascript" src="./three.js"></script>
  <script text="text/javascript" src="./script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

> You don't need to mention `global.d.ts` file anywhere, just have it in root folder.

**`script.js`**
[image]

That would be it

Comment: After spending time with above solution, suggestions doesn't come up for nested objects.

Comment: What do you mean nested objects?