# vscode get code suggestions for React without importing modules

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

Maybe this question has already been asked, but I wasn't able to find anything regarding the matter.

I'm currently trying to build a simple website using firebase in combination with React. I'm using vscode as my IDE. While the process of building the site itself is going quite well, I'm still having some issues getting used to vscode's code suggestions.

```
'use strict';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

let element = <h1>Hello world test</h1>;
ReactDOM.render(
    element,
    document.querySelector('#root')
);
```

In my file app.jsx I'm calling the method `ReactDOM.render(...)`. Here is where my issue comes into play. When I specifically import the class **ReactDOM** (`import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';`), my code suggestions work as expected. All available methods with their arguments are suggested, etc. Unfortunatly though, my browser does not like those import statements and throws an error. I am aware that I can use tools like webpack or browserify to solve this issue, but since the ReactDOM-class is available without the import anyways, I don't really see the imminent need to use those tools.

I was just wondering whether I could configrue vscode to just suggest these classes and their methods without explicitly importing them. Thanks for the help!

(In case this was unclear, here's what I want to happen, but **without** importing ReactDOM:
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "the ReactDOM class is available without the import anyways"? If you simply omit the import the code should not work in the browser either, right?

Comment: I think since I included `react.development.js` & `react-dom.development.js` in my index.html file, this class among others is available without explicitly having to import it. I tried it and it works without the import aswell.

Comment: In that case, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53390495/3083470) might help.